# How to migrate a closed question to super user?

Tags: discussion

There is a [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/420456/1577396), which I think is suitable for Superuser. I flagged it to the moderator, and the moderator declined saying this:

[image]

The moderator saying that there is a standard way of migration. I believe I can do that by clicking on close button. But as you can see the question is awaiting to get reopened:

[image]

In that case, how should I migrate?

Comment: SuperUser is already listed in the close vote dialogue (2nd) stage. There's no moderator intervention needed. That's why your flag was declined.

Comment: I think I didn't explain well here. The question was awaiting to get reopen and then later only I can close it. Now I am not going to observe everytime whether the post has been opened or not.

Comment: @Mr_Green Yes I've been overlooking that in a 1st glance. Edited a bit to make that clearer.

Comment: Actually, you cannot. If there's sufficient reason, a CM might migrate it, though you must make a good case in your custom flag or meta-post. And you didn't, you didn't even get across that it needs that high-level intervention to get done at all.

Comment: That (old) question would be off-topic for [su] - either "Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic." or "Primarily opinion-based. Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise." - take your pick ;)

Comment: I learned many things from that question and now it is getting deleting (_currently 8 votes to delete and one vote to reopen by me_). I don't care if it is deleted, I kept screenshot for myself. I thought to ask here thinking about others and I will not do any further requests to anyone. You guys can do whatever you think is best. Thanks.

Comment: @Mr_Green: Well, I think it's a good candidate for a histo-lock. Just ask for that, citing high votes, views, pending delete-votes, and it being clearly off-topic.

Comment: Well, I flagged for locking. We'll see.